# Trying to get distance data from distance matrix api always returning NULL

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

Sorry for bad english.
Im trying to access distance data using retrofit and moshi for parsing the json, here's the json response

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "Jl. Juanda 7A No.3, Air Hitam, Kec. Samarinda Ulu, Kota Samarinda, Kalimantan Timur 75243, Indonesia"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "Jl. Dayak Modang No.28, Sempaja Sel., Kec. Samarinda Utara, Kota Samarinda, Kalimantan Timur 75131, Indonesia"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "2.9 mi",
                        "value": 4687
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "11 mins",
                        "value": 651
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

and here's my retrofit call and getDistance method i use

```
//THIS CALL IS INSIDE COUROUTINE SCOPE
RetrofitBuilder(ConstantUtil.DISTANCE_API_URL).apiService.getDistance(origin = "${param[0]},${param[1]}", destination = "${param[2]},${param[3]}")

//GET DISTANCE METHOD
@GET("maps/api/distancematrix/json")
    suspend fun getDistance(
        @Query(value = "units") units: String = "metric",
        @Query(value = "origins") origin: String,
        @Query(value = "destinations") destination: String,
        @Query(value = "key") key: String = ConstantUtil.API_KEY
    ): DistanceResponseData
```

and here's DistanceResponseData "POJO" i use

```
data class DistanceResponseData (
    @field:Json(name = "rows") val rows: List<Rows>
)

data class Rows (
    @field:Json(name = "elements") val elements: List<Elements>
)

data class Elements (
    @field:Json(name = "distance") val distance: ItemData,
    @field:Json(name = "duration") val duration: ItemData,
    @field:Json(name = "status") val status: String
)

data class ItemData (
    @field:Json(name = "text") val rawText: String,
    @field:Json(name = "value") val rawValue: Int
)
```

if i log the returned response from call, i got every data i need, from rows down to data inside elements, but when i'm trying to access only distance from elements object, it always return null value, see code below.

```
//Here's when i log the DistanceResponseData object returned from call (got all data i need)
2020-02-06 13:42:55.232 20358-20358/com.vjtechsolution.kurir.service I/System.out: debug: distance data DistanceResponseData(rows=[Rows(elements=[{distance={text=4.9 km, value=4887.0}, duration={text=13 mins, value=766.0}, status=OK}])])

//But when im trying to access only the distance data using ${distanceData.rows[0].elements[0], it return null value for everything, even the DistanceResponseData log that worked before became null
2020-02-06 13:47:07.515 21107-21107/com.vjtechsolution.kurir.service I/System.out: debug: distance data DistanceResponseData(rows=[Rows(elements=[Elements(distance=null, duration=null, status=OK)])])
2020-02-06 13:47:07.516 21107-21107/com.vjtechsolution.kurir.service I/System.out: debug: distance elements Elements(distance=null, duration=null, status=OK)

//below code i use for logging the result
println("debug: distance data $distanceData")
println("debug: distance elements ${distanceData.rows[0].elements[0]}")
```

can someone explain why this happen? and how to fix it? it's been 2 days now i've been stuck with this problem.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have some information missing, F.E you don't have the correct annotation over the class.
Here's a nice guide.
https://proandroiddev.com/getting-started-using-moshi-for-json-parsing-with-kotlin-5a460bf3935a

Comment: can you give code example? i've tried adding @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) on those data classes, still not working. it even crash my app with this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter

Comment: You know what, this does fix the problem. adding @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) on those data classes, and make sure to add this to dependencies 

`def moshi_version = "1.9.2"
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version")`

thankyou